# C - Recursively reverse string from one file into another file

Tags: c, string, recursion, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string from a text file using recursion into another text file. The reversed string will be stored in a char array, and buffer will become that array. buffer will then be fprintf-ed to the new file. This is what I have so far.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>

        int
        reverse(char *ch, char *str)    //receives "buffer" as argument. str traverses ch
        {
            char array[20]; //will store the reversed string

            if(*str == '\0')
                return 0;   //arrived at end of string
            return(reverse(ch, str+1) + 1);      //don't know if this is correct
        }

//I want to use the returned number as the index number. For example, if I have
//string "abcd", string[0]='d', string[1]='c', string[2]='b', string[3]='a'. Problem is,
//how do I do it?


        int main(int argc, char *argv[])    //argv[1] is input file. argv[2] is output file printed backwards
        {   
            FILE *fp1, *fp2;
            char *p, buffer[20];    //p points to buffer

            fp1 = fopen("a.txt", "r");
            if(fp1 == NULL)
            {
                printf("The file does not exist.\n");
                return 0;
            }

            p = buffer;
            while(fgets(buffer, 20, fp1) != NULL)   //reads the first 20 characters of file.txt into buffer
            {
                reverse(buffer, p); //passes "buffer" as argument
                fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", buffer);
            }

            printf("File %s has been successfully reversed into file %s!\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
            fclose(fp1);
            fclose(fp2);
            return 0;
        }
```

Since I am new to recursion, I only have the faintest idea of how to implement my reverse function.

Comment: I suggest you practice writing recursive functions using simpler examples; reversing a string in-place in C (as it appears you're trying to do) is not the easiest exercise in recursion. Fibonacci is a good first-time exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing a string is easier and faster via an iterative loop, but to make a recursive function you could have the function reverse the starting and ending chars, then repeat the process with the smaller string

```
abcde 
^   ^  first call
 ^ ^   next call
  ^    end

---

void reverse(char *s, char *e) {
  char tmp = *s;
  *s++ = *e;
  *e-- = tmp;
  if (e > s) reverse (s, e);
}
```

Where *s* points to the 1st char and *e* to the last char. Note that the initial string must have a length > 0 (or a test could be added to the function).

Exemple

```
int main () {
    char x[] = "abcde";  
    reverse(x, x+strlen(x)-1);  
    printf("%s\n", x);  
    return 0;  
}
```

outputs `edcba`.